# TCP not working for custom network device driver

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

We have developed an ASIC for Power Line Communications and are developing a ethernet device driver for the same. The chip is connected to our host processor (iMX233 ARM9) via Serial Peripheral Interface. The Kernel Module we have developed, registers an ethernet device "gvspi" when loaded. While receiving. we get the ethernet frames from the ASIC over SPI and store it in a byte array and then allocate an sk_buff, cope the data from the array to this sk_buff and pass it on to the TCP/IP layers. During transmit, we send the ethernet frame (byte array retrieved via sk_buff->data) over SPI to the ASIC which then puts it out onto the Power Lines.

We have a setup like this:

**ARM Board1** --SPI--> **ASIC** ---Power Line---> **ASIC** --SPI--> **ARM Board2**

Both ARM boards running Linux kernel version 2.6.31

We are able to ping (using ping) the ARM boards from each other using our driver.
We are able to exchange UDP packets in both directions (using iperf) between the ARM Boards.
BUT we are not able to establish TCP connections between the two board (using telnet/telnetd or iperf).

It seems that the only the frames containing TCP are not being processed by the TCP/IP layer. Could this be the case? Are we populating the sk_buff properly before passing it to the upper layers?

Here is the appropriate section of the driver code which creates, populates and passes the sk_buff to the upper layers (u32 rx_data and u8 rx_len store the just received ethernet frame):

```
skb1 = alloc_skb((rx_len + NET_IP_ALIGN), GFP_ATOMIC);
skb_reserve(skb1, NET_IP_ALIGN);
skb_put(skb1, rx_len);
memcpy(skb1->data, rx_data, rx_len );               
skb1->protocol = eth_type_trans(skb1,gvspi_dev);
skb_reset_network_header(skb1);
skb_reset_transport_header(skb1);

gvspi_dev->stats.rx_bytes += skb1->len;
gvspi_dev->stats.rx_packets++; 

printk("Frame sent to TCP/IP layer...");

if (netif_rx_ni (skb1) != NET_RX_SUCCESS) {
    kfree_skb (skb1);
    gvspi_dev->stats.rx_dropped++;      
    return ERROR;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So we were able to find out the problem - RTFM category problem.
We had assigned the custom ethernet driver the MAC address as 11:22:33:44:55:66 which is of course a multicast address (see diagram [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Address_details))

Also for those who want the details:
Look at line number [1615](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/net/ipv4/tcp_ipv4.c?v=2.6.25.8#L1615) of tcp_v4_rcv() in tcp_ipv4.c of kernel sources.

The sk_buff which is sent to this TCPv4 receive function comes preset with [PACKET_MULTICAST](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/include/linux/if_packet.h?v=2.6.25.8#L28) from the lower layer whenever we use a multicast MAC address. 
Hence the sk_buff was getting rejected at this point, because the received frame was not specifically directed to our host as required by TCP. Multicast is only valid in connectionless protocols like UDP etc.